# Spring Data: How to lock a row in a transaction and make other transactions wait until it is released?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I have a `@Transactional` method where I request a record using `findById()` from a Spring Data repository.

Now I want to lock this object in a way that other `@Transactional` methods if executed in parallel will wait until the lock is released.

**What I tried:** I went through the documentation of [@Lock](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Lock.html) and [LockModeType](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/LockModeType.html) but I still can't figure out if it covers my case.

Another option would be `select for update` on a DB level, but I am not sure it is the best option.

**Q:** How to lock an Entity object (db row) in a spring data transaction and make other transactions wait?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you want is called **Pessimistic locking**. Spring Data through JPA specification supports that. There are two modes of pessimistic locking available:

I think you are mixing up Transaction isolation with Locking.  Through `@Transactional` annotation you can specify isolation which is applied to the connection, while through spring-data @Locking you can define the locking mode. The Lock mode is not related to the transaction isolation specified on `@Transactional`. Effectively if the isolation is SERIALIZEABLE you would not need locking via JPA or spring-data, because the database will take care of it. The locks will be DB controlled in this case.

When you define locking the control is in your hands. Here is a description of the pessimistic lock types.

**PESSIMISTIC_WRITE** - all transactions including the read only ones will be blocked until the transaction holding the lock is complete. Dirty reads are not allowed.

**PESSIMISTIC_READ** - when you have this mode , concurrent transactions can read the data of the locked row. All updates need to obtain PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock.

On top of this you can specify a timeout for the locking transaction completion.

Comment: Thank you. Should I annotate `findById()` method from the repository, or the `@Transactional` method where I call it?

Comment: Annotate your repository method that requires the locking.

Comment: I see where your confusion is spawning from I will update my answer.

Comment: I have a different kinda requirement.. I want my other transactions to terminate immidiately(not wait till the lock is released) when they see that the resource is already locked